# Scrolling after reaching a certain position using javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

Little disclaimer: I'm not a native english speaker.
My page contains of 3 basic blocks, each of them is a size of a window. Header, an article and footer. I know that i shouldn't mess with the way page is controlled by the user but i have that idea where after reaching a certain point on page the view scrolls down/up showing the whole block/div. So far "prototype" looks like this:

```
            var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
            var header = document.getElementById('header');
            var headerHeight = $("#header").height();

            if(yOffset >= headerHeight2){
                $("body,html").animate(
                    {
                        scrollTop : 500                       
                    }, 400); 
            }
```

My biggest problem with it it's that it only works when i srcoll down and reload my page.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are describing it, it seems as if your code is run right when the page is loaded. What you need to do here is find a way to run your scroll code when you reach a certain point.

Since you seem to be using jquery I will try to give you an example of how this can be accomplished:

```
// we can fetch the header and store it into a variable right away
// so that we don't fetch it on every scroll action.
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;

// This is fetched here to minimize the amount of
// jquery searches we do inside the 'onScroll'-function
// since it is being called multiple times
var elementToAnimate = $("body,html");

// Here we tell jquery that we want to run this function
// every time the window is scrolled.
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Here I just pasted your code since you said it worked.
    yOffset = window.pageYOffset;

    if(yOffset >= headerHeight2){
        elementToAnimate.animate(
            {
                scrollTop : 500                       
            }, 400); 
    }
});
```

I haven't had the time to try this, but from your description it seems as if it should work. Please comment if it doesn't and I'll fix it.

Please ask if I didn't explain it well enough :)

Comment: When i want to get position of the middle block/article it always displays 0. I'm drawing it like that var articleScroll = $("#article").scrollTop(); .  And in the animate method i set scrollTop to articleScroll. By that i want to sroll so user can see whole middle block and it doesn't work.

Comment: I menaged to fix one of the problem. The one with scrolling to the right position simply by doing that like this in animate scrollTop: $("#article").offset().top. But the problem is that it only works when i scroll the page and then refresh.

Comment: I put console.log into $(window).scroll(function()... to check the value of yOffset while scrolling it displays 0 until i reload the page. Then it sets to article offset.top.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure if I understand what you are describing.
First things first, is the $(window).scroll( function run every time you scroll?

If it is, then great. Since you have three different elements you want to "snap into position" once you get close to them the actual logics for when to animate is going to be a bit trickier than just if a > b and so on.

Can you try showing an example with https://jsfiddle.net/ maybe? Or edit your post so that all your (well, the parts you're talking about at least) javascript is shown?

Comment: My username is the same as here: noobski. I've set this project to public.Is there a way to message smb on stackoverflow? This tread is getting unnecessary messy.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jquery you can use $(window).scroll() event to get actual scroll, than compare it to headerHight like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var yOffset = $(window).scrollTop()
if(yOffset >= headerHeight2){
}
})
```

You got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Look into Waypoint http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ 
and use the offset option to control when the function should be invoked.
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/

This gives you very good control of how and when to trigger actions when user scrolls the page.